# Can you buy Apple Care from eBay after purchase iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applecare

I see advertisements on eBay selling Apple Care for half the price. I bought my iPhone 6 a week ago.

Can I still buy discounted Apple Care from eBay?

Answer (score 1):

**Caveat Emptor**

You might be buying a sealed, boxed product at a reasonable price…
…only to discover it's only valid in Outer Mongolia.

Different countries have different statutory requirements & Applecare varies country to country.

I'd be more circumspect.

Read this before even considering it - https://www.apple.com/support/products/iphone.html
***but*** make sure to swap to your own country via the flag icon in the very bottom right corner of the page before reading it.

Comment: It's great if you are from Outer Mongolia though.